# Unit test AngularJS directive with template containing ng-if

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine

I am trying to test the next angular directive. It listens to **ui-route** **$stateChange** event to show a progress indicator.

```
angular.module('sm.components.progress', ['ui.router'])

.directive('smProgress', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div class="in-progress" ng-if="isRouteLoading">' +
                '<span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span>' +
              '<div/>',

    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.isRouteLoading = false;

      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
        function() {
          $scope.isRouteLoading = true;
        });

      $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess',
        function() {
          $scope.isRouteLoading = false;
        });
    }
  };
});
```

This is my test code:

```
describe('smProgress', function() {
  var $compile, $rootScope, element, scope;

  beforeEach(module('sm.components.progress'));

  beforeEach(inject(function(_$compile_, _$rootScope_) {
    $compile = _$compile_;
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
  }));

  afterEach(function() {
    element.remove();
  });


  it('$rootScope.isRouteLoading should be false on start',
     function() {

    element = $compile('<sm-progress></sm-progress>')(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    expect(scope.isRouteLoading).toBe(false);

    $rootScope.$emit('$stateChangeStart');

    //The directive listen to the $stateChangeStart and     
    //scope.isRouteLoading become true as expected
    expect(scope.isRouteLoading).toBe(true);
    scope.$digest();

    // checks if the template is rendered when ng-if evaluates true
    // how?

  }));

});
```

The **ng-if** in the template start evaluating to `false`, so the element is removed from the DOM. When I emit manually the `$stateChangeStart` event, the directive listener works, but I can't find the element in the DOM.

How can I check if the template is added to then DOM when the **ng-if** evaluates to `true` again?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, This is the solution I found.

Is important to note two things:

1. The directive set **replace** to `true`.
2. The template has a **ng-if** directive.

This is what happens:

In the test, when the directive is compiled:

```
element = $compile('<sm-progress></sm-progress>')(scope);
```

`<sm-progress></sm-progress>` is replaced by:

```
<div class="in-progress" ng-if="isRouteLoading">
  <span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span>
<div/>
```

at the same time, ng-if is false, so the final rendered code is just a comment. This is how **ng-if** works naturally.

```
<!-- ngIf: isRouteLoading -->
```

When **$stateChangeStart** is fired, **scope.isRouteLoading** goes to `true`, that makes **ng-if** reinsert the template to the DOM. But in that point **element** is equal to:

```
<!-- ngIf: isRouteLoading -->
```

Is impossible to find inside of it the directive template.

```
// THE TEST FAILS
var progressEl = angular.element(element).find('in-progress');
expect(progressEl.length).toBeGreaterThan(0);
```

The solution is to wrap the html text in a **div** or any other element. So ng-if will operate inside of it and we can inspect what happen then.

```
it('scope.isRouteLoading should be false on start', function() {

    // wrap sm-progress with a div tag
    element = $compile('<div><sm-progress></sm-progress></div>')(scope);
    scope.$digest();

    expect(scope.isRouteLoading).toBe(false);

    // In this point element compiles to:
    // <div class="ng-scope"><!-- ngIf: isRouteLoading --></div>

    $rootScope.$emit('$stateChangeStart');
    expect(scope.isRouteLoading).toBe(true);
    scope.$digest();

    // Now element compiles to:
    // <div class="ng-scope">
    //     <!-- ngIf: isRouteLoading -->
    //     <div class="sm-progress ng-scope" ng-if="isRouteLoading">
    //         <span>.</span><span>.</span><span>.</span>
    //     </div>
    //     <!-- end ngIf: isRouteLoading -->
    // </div>

    // Now the test pass.
    var progressEl = angular.element(element).find('.in-progress');
    expect(progressEl.length).toBeGreaterThan(0); //element is present

  });
```

A jsfiddle.net with the code working http://jsfiddle.net/fwxgyjwc/13/

I hope I have explained well enough. My English is not very good.

Comment: @PankajParkar have you even test your own code. Don't vote down before you be sure what you are posting. Here I make a test to show you that your code fail again: http://jsfiddle.net/fwxgyjwc/11/.

Read my answer carefully.

Comment: Your code has another mistake, you put `except` instead of `expect`. But this does not matter, because you can't find '.in-progress' class inside of `<!-- ngIf: isRouteLoading -->`. I think it is pretty easy to understand that.

Comment: Did you tried console.log(element.find('.in-progress')) in test case

Comment: `console.log(element.find('.in-progress'));`

`LOG: {length: 0, prevObject: {0: <!-- ngIf: isRouteLoading -->, length: 1}, context: undefined, selector: '.in-progress'}`

Comment: Well I already make work my test. So, thanks for expending your time helping me @PankajParkar . :).

Comment: Sorry for my bad..I'll try to look at it in my night..its not working without wrapper element to directive.Thanks :) Cheers +1 for your efforts